# Why does the second piston accelerates slower than first? Why it happens so?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

[image]

In the image above we can have $A2>A1$.
We know it from Newton second law that $F=m×a$. It means that if we apply large force on any object then, it will accelerate with large value too.

My Confusion here is,
If the force on second piston is greater than force on first piston then, Second piston must accelerate faster by Newtons law.

But on the other hand, We know that it doesn't happen as it can violate law of conservation of energy.

Why it happens so?

Comment: How do you think the masses of the two pistons compare?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the continuity equation?  Moving piston 1 some distance $d_{1}$ may barely move piston 2 at all...

Comment: @honeste_vivere If the the second piston is continuously pushed by $F2$ force then it must accelerate faster than first piston by Newtons law of motion.

Comment: @Chet Miller "How do you think the masses of the two pistons compare?" what kind of answer is this?

Comment: We can assume that the mass of second piston is very less or equal to first piston. Now the $F/m = a $ relation says that Pidton two must accelerate faster.

Comment: PredakingAskboss - Again, if you look at the continuity equation, you will see that for an incompressible fluid, the total volume is constant, thus A*v = constant.  Since the area of the pistons are constant then what would that imply?

Comment: @PredakingAskboss In your analysis, you omitted the mass times acceleration of the fluid.

Comment: @honeste_vivere do you agree that there is force $F2$ on piston 2 where $F2>F1$. If yes, what second law of Newton tells us? It would simply mean that the net force on an object(here piston) is equal to the product of mass and acceleration of the object.  It seems like either the force $F2$ is not continuously applied on piston 2.......

Comment: ...... let's use word $ P2$for piston 2.  The fluid first applies a force on $P2$ and get an acceleration and looses contact with fluid, then the air drag and gravity slows it down, the $P2$ again gets in contact with  fluid and pushed/pulled with force $F2$ . In such way the force is not continuously applied and the resulted work done becomes the same as input by piston 1

Comment: The molecules of the fluid act in paralel so the force is strong but they have more momentum than energy, in other words they are slow and cannot transfer or add enough velocity per time to the piston....

Comment: @JankoBradvica Even if the fluid is slow or the $F2$ is not continuous the fluid is applying that force and it means that it must be trying to accelerate with acceleration that gives $F2$ as resultant force. And if they are accelerate fast they will lose contact with previous layer of fluid and this is how Force becomes continuous     am I right